# How to automatically collapse DatePicker in a form when other field is being edited?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I got a simple SwiftUI view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddItemView: View {
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Title", text: $title)
                DatePicker(
                    selection: $date,
                    in: Date()...,
                    displayedComponents: .date,
                    label: { Text("Date") }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddItemView()
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve the following:
If `DatePicker` is expanded (user tapped date picker, picker showing wheel to select date) and then starts typing text in `TextField`, `DatePicker` should automatically switch to initial, minimized mode (just showing label and selected date). Please take a look at screenshot. This is a behaviour in a stock Calendar.app, for example, when creating events.

[image]

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach. The idea is to reset `DatePicker` component for each of events result in editing.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var pickerReset = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TitleTextField()

                DatePicker(
                    selection: $date,
                    in: Date()...,
                    displayedComponents: .date,
                    label: { Text("Date") }
                ).id(self.pickerReset)
            }
        }
    }

    private func TitleTextField() -> some View {
        let boundText = Binding<String>(
            get: { self.title },
            set: { self.title = $0; self.pickerReset = UUID() }
        )
        return TextField("Title", text: boundText, onEditingChanged: { editing in
            if editing {
                self.pickerReset = UUID()
            }
        })
    }
}
```